# How is LMAX Disruptor garbage collector friendly

Tags: java, concurrency, disruptor-pattern, lmax

I am trying to understand how lmax disruptor is GC friendly. I see that the event objects on the ring are re-used, however, the "data" that is "set" on these objects are on the heap so it feels like the garbage collection benefit is limited to 1 object less per event.  if the 'data' is of primitive data type then there's nothing additional on the heap, so the benefit in this case is very clear. Is 1 object less to GC per event significant or there's more to this than I understand w.r.t GC.

This article http://mechanitis.blogspot.com/2011/06/dissecting-disruptor-whats-so-special.html says *the garbage collector has pretty much nothing to do here* - this isnt very obvious to me, hence the question.

Comment: Did you read the comments below that article? The author says they *are* using primitive data, resp. byte arrays they recycle. That ring buffer is not really solving any problem, as regarding the actual problems, the following sentence of the article applies: “*That's because the ring buffer itself isn't responsible for these things, we've moved these concerns outside of the data structure.*”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ring buffer acts as a pool of objects - when you claim a sequence you can copy data into the event and when all the event handlers have finished processing the event will be returned to the ring buffer again.

The trick is make sure that you copy the data into the event and therefore that the event can hold all the different types of data you might want to communicate between the producers and consumers.  If you simply allocate an object on the heap on the producer side and pass a reference to this object to the event then you will obviously not reduce the memory pressure on the GC at all.

[Another approach](https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2012/10/compact-off-heap-structurestuples-in.html) is to have an event which is simply an offset into some off-heap memory which can be interpreted as different types of objects by using flyweights.

Comment: Can you provide some examples or references for the other approach you mentioned.

Comment: You can see an example in the performance tests https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/perftest/java/com/lmax/disruptor/offheap/OneToOneOffHeapThroughputTest.java.  I've also added a link to Martin's blog post in my answer.

Comment: if event data is not instance of primitive types,  it seems take no effect on memory reuse.

Comment: You can think of the events as an object pool and when you claim an event from the ring buffer you get an empty object which you then need to fill with primitve data.  The event itself can contain sub objects which should be instantiated at the same time as the event.